# JS - вывод текста в модальное окно

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, текст, всплывающее-окно

Всем привет. У меня есть карточка товара, и необходимо сделать так, чтоб при нажатии кнопки передавалась информация с описания товара - в модальное окно.

Пытался сделать это через innerHTML/outerHTML, но описание из одной карточки - передается на все модальные окна. Тайтл в карточке может быть уникальным, соотвественно - в каождом модальном окне должен быть уникальный тайтл.

Для каждой карточки свое окно создавать - не рационально, по этому прошу помощи))
В общем, в html - примерно такая структура:

Карточки товаров:

```
<div class="catalog-item">
                <div class="catalog-item__wrapper">
                    <div class="catalog-item__content">
                        <img src="" alt="" class="catalog-item__img">
                            <div class="catalog-item__subtitle">Наручные часы</div>
                            <div class="catalog-item__descr">описание</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <button -data-modal="order" class="button button_mini">Купить</button>
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="catalog-item">
                <div class="catalog-item__wrapper">
                    <div class="catalog-item__content">
                        <img src="" alt="" class="catalog-item__img">
                            <div class="catalog-item__subtitle">Кожаные ботинки</div>
                            <div class="catalog-item__descr">описание</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <button -data-modal="order" class="button button_mini">Купить</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Модальное окно:

```
<div class="modal" id="order">
        <div class="modal__close">&times;</div>
        <div class="modal__subtitle">Ваш заказ:</div>
        <div class="modal__descr">Тут должен быть тайтл\описание из карточки</div>
</div>
```

P.s. Такой механизм легко проворачивается в jQuery, примерно таким образом:

```
$('.button_mini').each(function(i)) {
$(this).on('click', function() {
    $('#order .modal_descr').text($('.catalog-item__subtitle').eq(i).text());
    
})}
```

Но, мне не хотелось бы подключать jQuery ради этого, по этому хотелось бы реализовать подобный функционал на нативном js

Вот, кстати моя неудачная попытка попытка реализовать это:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".button_mini").forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function () {
        document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.add('is-visible');
        document.querySelector("#order").classList.add('is-visible');
        document.querySelector('.modal__descr').outerHTML = (document.querySelector('.catalog-item__subtitle').item.outerHTML);

    });

});
```

Comment: `item.addEventListener ...` циклом пробегаете по кнопкам, и слушаете клик - хорошо. Дальше подумайте что ищет `document.querySelector('.catalog-item__subtitle')`. И `('.catalog-item__subtitle').item.outerHTML` - тут что-то странное, то такое `item`

Comment: У меня была надежда, что "iem" будет работать аналогично как на jQuery .eq(i), как в примере выше, но нет. Я так же пытался такую махинацию провернуть через использование цикла for (let i =0; i < item.length; i++), а дальше похожие действия выполнялись, как в forEach (в примере), но задавал индекс "[i]". По логике он должен был давать каждому тайтлу свой индекс по порядку, а затем при клике отображать этот тайтл (с соотвсествующем индексом\номером) в модальном окне, но что-то пошло не так)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогли решить проблему с помощью [делегирования событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation)

```
const modal = document.querySelector('#order');
const modalDescription = modal.querySelector('.modal__descr');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

document.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const isButtonMini = event.target.matches('.catalog-item .button_mini');

  if (!isButtonMini) {
    return;
  }
  const parent = event.target.closest('.catalog-item');
  const subtitle = parent.querySelector('.catalog-item__subtitle');

  modalDescription.textContent = subtitle.textContent;

  modal.classList.add('is-visible');
  overlay.classList.add('is-visible');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

После того, как циклом пробежали по кнопкам, слушаете клик. И потом вы ищите `document.querySelector('.catalog-item__subtitle')` НО `document.querySelector` - находит первый элемент с таким классом, и дальше не ищет. То есть в вашем случае при клике на любую кнопку вы всегда находите `<div class="catalog-item__subtitle">Наручные часы</div>`.

Вам после клика на кнопку нужно найти родителя, чтобы в нем найти заголовок `item.closest('.catalog-item')` - нашли родителя и потом ищете заголовок `wrap.querySelector('.catalog-item__subtitle')`

Пример:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".button_mini").forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const wrap = item.closest('.catalog-item')
    document.querySelector('.modal__descr').textContent = wrap.querySelector('.catalog-item__subtitle').textContent;
  });

});
```

```html
<div class="catalog-item">
  <div class="catalog-item__wrapper">
    <div class="catalog-item__content">
      <img src="" alt="" class="catalog-item__img">
      <div class="catalog-item__subtitle">Наручные часы</div>
      <div class="catalog-item__descr">описание</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button -data-modal="order" class="button button_mini">Купить</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="catalog-item">
  <div class="catalog-item__wrapper">
    <div class="catalog-item__content">
      <img src="" alt="" class="catalog-item__img">
      <div class="catalog-item__subtitle">Кожаные ботинки</div>
      <div class="catalog-item__descr">описание</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button -data-modal="order" class="button button_mini">Купить</button>
</div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="order">
  <div class="modal__close">&times;</div>
  <div class="modal__subtitle">Ваш заказ:</div>
  <div class="modal__descr">Тут должен быть тайтл\описание из карточки</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Ваш ответ полезен, и возьму его на заметку, на будущее ))
Но в моем случае больше практичным решением проблемы будет - способом, который я оставил ниже. (делегирование событий)